# Pandas perform math on index

Tags: python, pandas

How can I perform math operations on the index in a Pandas data frame?

Trying `df1[index] = df1[index] + 2` returns error `KeyError: 'None of [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)] are in the [columns]'` because `df1[index]` doesn't return the actual array.

A reason to do this would be if I want to concatenate two datafames column-wise on the index, but I know the index in my second data frame is offset by 2.

Comment: are you looking for something similar to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123545/operations-on-pandas-dataframe-index

Comment: Access the index with [`DataFrame.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) -> `df1.index = df1.index + 2`

Comment: @Rishi Yes, that's exactly what I needed, not sure how I missed it. This Q can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: if it's just for concatinating, you can set ignore_index =True

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks, that's exactly what I needed; df1[index] gave me issues, but this works, thanks

Comment: @Mohammad yes, I can do that but then I must specify a key or else there is no way to control the match